# How to make wordpress blog completely invisible to public [Not Private]

Tags: wordpress, locking, invisible

I want to close a wordpress blog I have from the public and keep it only for myself.

I know I can set it to private but it shows an uggly log-in page and I dont want people trying to access it (using random usernames/pass etc) or think that its still open but its for members with accounts or anything like that.

I would like the blog to point to a " server not found " for the public and when I am logged in as admin to be able to see my posts and backend aswell as frontend.

How can I make this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be the following:

```
function is_login_page() {
    return in_array( $GLOBALS['pagenow'], array( 'wp-login.php', 'wp-register.php' ) );
}

function wpse_make_blog_private() {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && ! is_admin() && ! is_login_page() ) { 
        global $wp_query;
        $wp_query->set_404();
    }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'wpse_make_blog_private' );
```

It will show a 404 on all pages but still allow you to login. Logged in users will see the site as normal.

On your request to show a completely broken site add the following code to functions.php. Be aware that this is instead of the code above.

```
function is_login_page() {
    return in_array( $GLOBALS['pagenow'], array( 'wp-login.php', 'wp-register.php' ) );
}

function wpse_make_blog_private() {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && ! is_admin() && ! is_login_page() ) { 
        die();
    }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'wpse_make_blog_private' );
```

You have the option of using wp_die instead to add an error message with minimal styling. See: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_die

Comment: Thank you for the answer NAthan, where should I put this in header.php index.php ? I guess the approach to this is to make it private blog and use the above code? When someone isnt logged in would it give him a 404 page like when a site doesnt exist or the "inner 404" using the template of the website and displaying 404?

Comment: Put it in functions.php. Yep that's exactly what it does.

Comment: An odd thing has happened, I tried to find the "I would like my blog to be visible only to users I choose" in Reading options in wordpress before I use the code above and its not there. Any idea what I could do? (I am using latest version of wordpress 3.8.1)

Comment: That's the first time I've heard of such an option.

Comment: I cant find a way to make it private, usually I could go in "Reading" => Making this blog private (something like this under the block search engines option)

Comment: That's something different entirely. All you're doing is preventing search engines from indexing the site.

Comment: How can I make it private? 
I tried to follow this guide: http://en.support.wordpress.com/settings/privacy-settings/#site-visibility-options
But I dont have the option "I would like my blog to be visible only to users I choose"

 When I use the above code it displays the template and whole site with a message saying " 404 message " is it possible to make it totally empty like a broken site or deleted site?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you wrap all the code you want to be visible to logged in users inside the following check:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
    // do stuff for logged in users
} else {
    // do stuff for guests / users that are not logged in
}
```

Comment: Should I place this in the header.php or in the index.php? I want the whole site to go "server not found" if im not logged in.

Comment: This should wrap around your content, whatever you'd like to show / hide.