# Make images private in Wordpress

Tags: php, .htaccess, wordpress

I'm making a site, that I would like to make private. The most important part, is that the images on the domain can't be seen, without the user logging in first. 
   So I would like all traffic to be redirected to www.DOMAINNAME.com/wp-admin (also for images), if the user isn't logged in.

Here's what I've tried:

1) Plugins. I've tried both [Wordpress Force Login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-force-login/) , the plugin [wp-require-login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-require-login/) and a [Coming soon page and Maintenance mode](https://wordpress.org/plugins/coming-soon/).

2) Adding a function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519805/how-to-make-wordpress-blog-completely-invisible-to-public-not-private). Which is this:

```
function is_login_page() {
    return in_array( $GLOBALS['pagenow'], array( 'wp-login.php', 'wp-register.php' ) );
}

function wpse_make_blog_private() {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && ! is_admin() && ! is_login_page() ) { 
    global $wp_query;
    $wp_query->set_404();
    }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'wpse_make_blog_private' );
```

Non of these things redirects the traffic, if I go to the direct URL for the image (such as http://www.DOMAINNAME.com/uploads/2015/10/foobar.jpg ).

Can that be done?

----------------- EDIT 1 --------------

Mevius pointed out, that Wordpress might not be loaded, if you type in the direct URL to an image, so he suggests, that it should be done on apache-level.

------------- END OF EDIT 1 -----------

Comment: I don't believe WordPress is even loaded if you directly access an image (as would be the case if you directly navigated to any other static asset on your server). You may have to do this at the Apache level

Comment: Hmm... Good point. Does that mean adding it to the htaccess-file, right? I'll just add that tag as well, on this question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can make this as complicated or as simple as you want. The simplest is to check the referrer as suggested by Hemnath Mouli but that can spoofed easily.

However, if you want to go really deep... ;)

Use .htacess file with a RewriteRule to rewrite all images into a PHP script that bootstraps Wordpress and checks the user's authentication status. Also you should add an .htaccess file to your images folder to deny direct access to the folder to exclude edge cases.

**WARNING: THIS CODE IS JUST PROOF OF CONCEPT TO GET YOU STARTED!!**

**.htaccess**

`RewriteRule ^(.*\.(jpg|gif|png))$ isAuthenticated.php?path=$1`

**isAuthenticated.php**

```
require_once("wp-blog-header.php");

$allowedExtensions = array("jpg", "gif", "png");

$path = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$_REQUEST["path"];
$pathInfo = pathinfo($path);

// Check if the Wordpress user is logged in and if the file extension is allowed
// @see https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in
if (!is_user_logged_in() || !in_array($pathInfo["extension"], $allowedExtensions)) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden");
    exit;
}

if(!file_exists($path)) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
    exit;
}

// Display the file and set the correct mimetype
$resource = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mimetype = finfo_file($resource, $path);
finfo_close($resource);

header("Content-Type: ".$mimetype);
readfile($path);
```

Comment: +1 That's the way to go when you don't want to change anything about current system. Anyway, it's better to put "private" files outside the public scope at the beginning, but that's almost the same result as this one

Answer (score 10):

Use `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg)$ - [F]
```

Returns 403 if you access image directly, but allows them to be displayed on site.

Comment: Really? did you try this? I'm asking out of curiosity.

Comment: This is definitely a naive solution, you can't rely on it

Answer (score 1):

Use .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg)$ - [F]
```

Answer (score -4):

The easiest way to do this is to add the images to posts and pages that are private. [image: Publishing a Private Page/Post]

Helpful Links:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Content_Visibility
https://en.support.wordpress.com/pages/page-visibility/

Comment: The images will still have a publicly accessible URL.