# Automatically restrict access to uploader/admin on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, permissions, media

I am trying to limit access to files uploaded through PHP/forms.  Access should be given only to uploader + admin.  I can't seem to prevent people from using direct links to access the files in the media library.  The process needs to be automated, with this security as the default.

I am looking for something secure/foolproof.  I have a relational database to check who uploaded the image.

I've tried using .htaccess for redirects to PHP pages and none of these solutions worked. [Make images private in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32954960/make-images-private-in-wordpress)

`RewriteRule ^(.*\.(jpg|gif|png))$ isAuthenticated.php?path=$1` this, specifically would be great if I could get it to work.  I have no experience debugging or writing .htaccess code, and have not found many resources online.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a custom user role or simply don’t want to use a plugin, then you can try this method instead. You will be able to modify it to meet your needs.

You’ll need to add the following code to your WordPress functions.php file or a site-specific plugin.

```
// Limit media library access

add_filter( 'ajax_query_attachments_args', 'wpb_show_current_user_attachments' );

function wpb_show_current_user_attachments( $query ) {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    if ( $user_id && !current_user_can('activate_plugins') && !current_user_can('edit_others_posts
') ) {
        $query['author'] = $user_id;
    }
    return $query;
}
```

This code uses current_user_can function to check if the user has the capability to activate plugins or edit other user’s posts. If they don’t, then it changes the query used to display media files and limit it to user’s ID.

Also for Image hotlinking protection you can use this in your .htaccess

```
#disable hotlinking of images with forbidden or custom image option
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?google.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ – [NC,F,L]
```

This code only allows images to be displayed if the request is originating from yourdomain.com or Google.com. Don’t forget to replace yourdomain.com with your own domain name.

Comment: The you would have to manually edit your functions.php file with the code.

Comment: Would I have to edit the functions.php file with every Wordpress update?  Would .htaccess make more sense, if I could get that to work?

Comment: Try this plugin -> https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-access-manager/

Comment: my answer was updated to include hotlinking protection from .htacess

Comment: @user2954658 I don't believe you can manage user roles access from .htaccess